# itemView problem when im using recyclerview

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I can't view my textviews can someone help

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XucDi.png

Comment: Please try to go over official basic documentation before asking a question. [doc](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: You look like you're trying to implement `onBindViewHolder`, which lets you access `itemView` through the `holder` parameter that gets passed in. The function you're writing there has neither of those things. Like the comment above says, you should read up on how to write these adapters and how the bits fit together

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.